# Real Time Calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a form where I want to dynamically show/update the value of an `input[text]` without getting the form submitted.

Take this as an example:

LEGEND:

`price=$60` (fixed value)

`8 Kilo = 1 Spin` [For every 8 kilos it will equate to 1 spin. 9kilos=2Spins]

`Amount = Spin*Price`

As a user types 10 in 'kilo', the 'spin' value will be updated and 'amount' value will be automatically be computed. The computation should happen real-time while user types.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="dataTables-example">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>SERVICE</th>
    <th>KILO</th>
    <th>SPINS</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>AMOUNT</th>
   </tr>
<tr>
<form id="new_transaction" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="scripts/add_transaction.php">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>WASH</td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kilo" id="kilo1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="spins" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value="$60" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount"readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

[THE FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DLqu.png)

[DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvZOA.png)

Comment: So where is your JS? All I see is a basic form... Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Add an `onchange` event handler

Comment: Wanna start from scratch.

Comment: If I understand this question, you want somebody to write your JavaScript for you? Or do you just want to know how to trigger the calucation?

Comment: I am looking for someone to help me with the script. I barely know javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add onchange="updateSpin()" and value="" to your kilo input, also add an id to your spins input and your amount input. Add a script to link jquery and then a script with your updateSpin function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function updateSpin(){
    var kilo = $(this).val();
    var spins = Math.ceil(kilo/8);
    //update spins
    $("#spinsID").val(spins);
    //update amount
    $("#amountID").val(spins);
}
</script>
```

Hope that might help.
EDIT** changing the floor function to ceil works also. Just a little simpler.

Comment: This really helped me. But what do you mean by "There must be overflow" ?

Comment: Glad to hear! by overflow, i meant that like if kilo=10 then kilo %(mod) 8 would return 2, meaning we're 2 units over our limit so increase spins by 1